# How to fix the error of Maximum call stack size exceeded when using pattern lab?

Tags: node.js, patternlab.io

In pattern lab `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error and I don't know why. I'm not doing anything that I haven't done before.

In `01-molecules/02-cart/cart.mustache` I have this code

```
{{#miniCart}}
<div class="mini_cart_item">
    <img class="mini_cart_image" src={{img}} alt="">
    <div class="mini_cart_info">
        <span>£{{price}}</span>
        <h4 class="mini_cart_title">{{title}}</h4>
    </div>
</div>
{{/miniCart}}
```

That data comes from `01-molecules/02-cart/cart.json`. It works fine.

Then I have `02-organisms/mini-cart.mustache` and the code is

```
<div class="mini_cart">
{{#miniCart}}
{{> cart}}
{{/miniCart}}
</div>
```

The `cart` comes from the molecule above, the data comes from `02-organisms/mini-cart.json`. Is is the some json code just with more objects.

That `{{> cart}}` throws the `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. If I remove that line of code and replace it with anything, like `{{title}}` the code just works.

What might be the problem?

---

To run pattern lab I am running this

```
/MyMAMP/www/2016/edition-node-gulp/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js patternlab:serve
```

From google search I tried this

```
/MyMAMP/www/2016/edition-node-gulp/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js patternlab:serve --stack_size=2048
```

but the result is the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintainer of Pattern Lab Node here.

`{{> cart}}` should be `{{> molecules-cart}}`

Give that a shot.

Comment: Relevant documentation: http://patternlab.io/docs/pattern-including.html

Answer (score 0):

remove reference to 'miniCart' template inside the 'cart' template

this causes an infinite recursion in template engine

Comment: I get the same error. I might have made the same mistake elsewhere in other templates